# Is the regression prediction from sklearn's DecisionTreeRegressor a simple average?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm trying to figure out exactly how the decision tree regression predictions are generated. It's not explained in detail in the documentation that I've covered.

From the [sklearn DecisionTreeRegressor documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor) on the **predict** function:

> For a classification model, the predicted class for each sample in X
>   is returned. For a regression model, the predicted value based on X is
>   returned.

So, are the predictions made from a simple average of the outputs from the leaf node that the new X value fell into, or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart) (in the last para), sklearn uses CART algorithm. And as noted [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart) (slide 29) CART simply outputs the average of leaf node a sample falls into.